# Initialize state with async function data NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I'm looking to initialize a state using an asynchronous function:

```js
...
export default function Catalog() {
  const [productsShow, setProductsShow] = useState(getAllProducts())

  ...
  return(
    ... Render products using `productsShow` ... 
  )
```

#### getAllProducts()

```js
...
export async function getAllProducts() {

    ...
    return productSet  // Of type Set()
}
```

The issue I have is the `productsShow` state is `undefined` when the page renders. I figure this because the page renders without waiting for the results of the `async` function to complete.  Is there a way to initialize the state with results?

I've tried using the `then()` function but this results in the same error:

```js
getAllProducts().then(initialProducts => {
    useEffect(() => {
      setProductsShow(preProducts => initialProducts)
    }, [productsShow])
  })
```

I'm using NextJS

There are some similar questions but differ in technologies used:

- [Initialize state with async data in Redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41786185/initialize-state-with-async-data-in-redux)
- [Can you use an async function to set initial state with useState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65390373/can-you-use-an-async-function-to-set-initial-state-with-usestate)

Comment: I don't see how the second link fails to provide an answer. Simply initialise with an empty array (`useState([])`) and resolve the products in an effect hook... `useEffect(() => { getAllProducts().then(setProductsShow) }, [])`

Comment: You might also be interested in Next's [pre-rendering](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#two-forms-of-pre-rendering) capabilities, particularly [static generation with data](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#static-generation-with-data)